# How to get the values of a key of a json file

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, android-studio

[image: Expected Result]How can i get the values of a json key in Java here is my code

```
    private void getWebApiData() {
        String WebDataUrl = "myjsonfileurl";
        new AsyncHttpTask.execute(WebDataUrl);
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String result = "";

            URL url;
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                if (result != null) {
                    String response = streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                    parseResult(response);
                    return result;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null) {
                newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), newsClassList);
                listView.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Data Loaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed to load data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private String streamToString(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        String line;
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;
        }

        // Close stream
        if (null != stream) {
            stream.close();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void parseResult_GetWebData(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("books");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject articleObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject sourceObject = articleObject.getJSONObject("A");

                String name = sourceObject.optString("name");

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My json file

```
{
  "books": [
    {
      "A": [
        {
          "Amazonite": {
            "name": "Amazonite",
            "image": "www.google.com"
          },
          "Amethyst": {
            "name": "Amethyst",
            "image": "www.google.com"
          }
        }
      ],
      "B": [
        {
          "Beryl": {
            "name": "Beryl",
            "image": "www.google.com"
          },
          "BloodStone": {
            "name": "Bloodstone",
            "image": "www.google.com"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What i would like is how to get the values of data under the Alphabet A that is Amazonite and Amethyst and the value of data under Alphabet B but the could i have just give me empty text field nothing no data is being populated.
I have tried with this code but the values retures "null"

```
    private void parseResult_GetWebData(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("books");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject articleObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = String.valueOf(articleObject.optJSONObject("A"));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `A` is a JSON array, so you should use `articleObject.optJSONArray("A")` instead.

Comment: tried this but am getting this the full string of the A node  "[
        {
          "Amazonite": {
            "name": "Amazonite",
            "image": "www.google.com"
          },
          "Amethyst": {
            "name": "Amethyst",
            "image": "www.google.com"
          }
        }
      ],"       what i what is just the key that is "Amazonite and Amethyst"

Comment: I just point out why you got `null` for variable `name`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you really want, but if you just want to get "Amazonite and Amethyst" as you responded under OP, you can try this:

**Code snippet**

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject articleObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray jsonArrayA = articleObject.getJSONArray("A");

    for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayA.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject obj = jsonArrayA.getJSONObject(j);
        System.out.println(obj.names());

        obj.names().forEach(e -> {
            System.out.println(obj.getJSONObject(e.toString()).get("name"));
        });
    }
}
```

**Console output**

> ["Amazonite","Amethyst"]
>   Amazonite
>   Amethyst

---

**Update**

I am not sure which **name** you want to retrieve because both `Amazonite` and `Amethyst` appear two times in JSON array `A`, so I provide two ways to show them as follows:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> innerNames = new ArrayList<>();
for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayA.length(); j++) {
    JSONObject obj = jsonArrayA.getJSONObject(j);
    JSONArray keys = obj.names();
    for (int k = 0; k < keys.length(); k++) {
        String name = keys.getString(k);
        String innerName = obj.getJSONObject(keys.optString(k)).getString("name");

        System.out.printf("name: %s, inner name: %s\n", name, innerName);

        names.add(name);
        innerNames.add(innerName);
    }
}
System.out.println(names.toString());
System.out.println(innerNames.toString());
```

**Console output**

> name: Amazonite, inner name: Amazonite
>   name: Amethyst, inner name: Amethyst
>   [Amazonite, Amethyst]
>   [Amazonite, Amethyst]

Comment: I am able to get the first result that is "["Amazonite","Amethyst"]" but what i want is the second option to get the data as separate string because am populating it in a listview 
i am using android studio so i need the result as a string not system.out.printIn as in regular java

but this coming as lambda expression "bj.names().forEach(e -> {
            System.out.println(obj.getJSONObject(e.toString()).get("name"));
        });" the ForEach line to be precise  please can your post the answer as a string in android studio

Comment: @Serenity Hi, I have updated my post but I am still not sure what you exactly want.

Comment: Thanks but want i want to display is just Amazonite and Amethyst separately not the whole data within it  i have edited my question with the expected result

Comment: @Serenity Updated, please check!

Comment: Thanks but am only getting one value in the both that is "Amethyst" and "Amethyst" the first value is not be populated it just repeating the same value sorry for inconveniences

Comment: @Serenity I am not familiar with Android development, so what kind of data type you want to use for display? String? List? Or something else?

Comment: "https://imgur.com/Trm4Bn0" please check the image i think that is probably the issue because i think the value in the highlight part of the image should be 0, and 1 not just 0 since there are two values am not really sure just a guess but am using list to populate the values

Comment: @Serenity In your JSON string, there is just **ONE** JSON object in JSON array `A`, so the highlight part of the image is 0.

Comment: thanks fixed that part but i am only getting the last value of the JSON "Amethyst" i am trying to populate the both keys under A to a list separately just like the image in my question but only the last value is being populated thank for your help so far

Comment: @Serenity According to your comment, I save `Amazonite` and `Amethyst` as a `List` in normal Java way. Please check again!